How can I get a file from a directory with just a name and no file extension in python 3.12
I can't really find any answers online but, I am trying to find a file (mainly images) in a directory with only the name of the file (since the files are named after users ids (1.png, 2.jpg, etc...)). Is there a way of doing this? or do I require the file extension. I have a feeling this should be possible since my code is written so that it is impossible for more than one image to contain the same name with a different extension. The images are also stored in a separate directory and nothing else goes in there. I would prefer to avoid looping through the directory as that can be pretty slow.
Any help would be appreciated.

Something has to loop through the directory -- the underlying OS-level interface has no facility for doing a lookup without a full name. Even if you delegate that to code you aren't writing yourself (as with glob.glob() or similar), it's still happening no matter what.

...if your directories are so large that iterating over their contents is slow, that means it's time to change your directory structure -- f/e, having one directory per user id so you can look that up in amortized constant time (on a modern filesystem with indexed directories -- not all filesystems in active use support that feature, but if your code is deployed to one that doesn't, it's 100% reasonable to complain to your sysadmin staff) and then just loop over its contents.

glob.glob('1.*') will return the list of files that match the pattern, and the search is done in C code.

Why do you need your files to have extensions at all in the first place?

@CharlesDuffy I need the files to have extensions as I am fetching images for profile pictures.

@InactiveGaming13, why does that mean they need to have extensions? Assuming your application is a web server, the remote client doesn't get the file type from the name, it gets it from the mime type in the HTTP headers, and you can build those by detecting the filetype (from the file's own header or footer content -- this is what libmagic does) without knowing its name at all. And if it's not a web server, major Python image libraries still support detection from file content without knowing the name.

Remember that file extensions are mostly a Windows thing -- in UNIXy systems relying on an extension for anything important is considered bad form, so software that originated in the UNIX world mostly doesn't care about them.

import glob

directory_path = "/path/to/your/directory"
file_name = "1"  # Name of the file without extension

# Search for all files with the specified name in the directory
matching_files = glob.glob(f"{directory_path}/{file_name}.*")

# Print the matching files
print(matching_files)

Behind the scenes, glob.glob() does loop through the directory to find matching files, but it's implemented efficiently and optimized for speed. It's generally faster than writing your own loop to search for files.
If performance is a concern, you might want to consider methods like indexing the filenames or using a database for even faster lookups.

You can use os.scandir
import os

def find_file_by_name(directory, filename):
  for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    if entry.is_file() and entry.name.split('.')[0] == filename:
      return entry.name  # return the full filename with extension
  return None

Although this does loop through the directory, os.scandir is quite fast.

You could use fnmatch.filter
filename = next(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('.'), "1.*"))


I dont think there is a way to do it without looping through the dir, because, even if your code isn't a loop, whatever function you call or method you use will be a loop.
if you are using os, you can do:
for filename in os.listdir('./dir'):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        print(f'File: {filename[:-4]}')
    elif filename.endswith(".jpeg"):
        print(f'File: {filename[:-5]}')


the :-3 will remove the last 3 chars of the filename
example: fun.py[:-3]   ->  fun
or:      fun.text[:-5] ->  fun

Not every extension is 3 characters long. Consider .jpeg vs .jpg; doesn't make any sense to hardcode a specific number when the extensions will differ.

this is true, I will edit the code so that it can handle such
